Jewish woman that engages in relations adulterous?
In Chumash Devarim parshat Ki tetzei 22:13 it states that if a man takes a wife and is intimate with her and then despises her and then makes libelous charges against her that she was not a virgin when he took her, why is she considered an adulterous woman?
She wasn't married when she lost her virginity so wouldn't that Moreso be considered a harlot? or a promiscuous woman. Why an adulterous?
13If a man takes a wife, is intimate with her and despises her,     יגכִּֽי־יִקַּ֥ח אִ֖ישׁ אִשָּׁ֑ה וּבָ֥א אֵלֶ֖יהָ וּשְׂנֵאָֽהּ:
[If a man takes a wife,] is intimate with her, and despises her: in the end he will…
וּבָא אֵלֶיהָ וּשְׂנֵאָֽהּ: סוֹפוֹ,
14and he makes libelous charges against her and gives her a bad name, saying, "I took this woman, and when I came to her, I did not find any evidence of virginity for her."        ידוְשָׂ֥ם לָהּ֙ עֲלִילֹ֣ת דְּבָרִ֔ים וְהוֹצִ֥א עָלֶ֖יהָ שֵׁ֣ם רָ֑ע וְאָמַ֗ר אֶת־הָֽאִשָּׁ֤ה הַזֹּאת֙ לָקַ֔חְתִּי וָֽאֶקְרַ֣ב אֵלֶ֔יהָ וְלֹֽא־מָצָ֥אתִי לָ֖הּ בְּתוּלִֽים:
make libelous charges against her: One sin leads to another sin. He transgressed [the negative commandment of] “You shall not hate [your brother in your heart]” (Lev. 19:17); so eventually he will come to [commit the sin of] slander (לָשׁוֹן הָרַע). - [Sifrei 22:87]
וְשָׂם לָהּ עֲלִילֹת דְּבָרִים: – עֲבֵרָה גּוֹרֶרֶת עֲבֵרָה, עָבַר עַל לֹא תִשְׂנָא, סוֹפוֹ לָבֹא לִידֵי לָשׁוֹן הָרָע (עי' ספרי):
this woman: We learn from here that he says nothing except in the presence of his opponent. — [Sifrei 22:89]
אֶת־הָֽאִשָּׁה הַזֹּאת: מִכָּאן שֶׁאֵין אוֹמֵר דָּבָר אֶלָּא בִּפְנֵי בַעַל דִּין (שם):
15Then the girl's father and her mother shall obtain evidence of the girl's virginity, and take it out to the elders of the city, to the gate.      טווְלָקַ֛ח אֲבִ֥י הַנַּֽעֲרָ֖ה (כתיב הנער) וְאִמָּ֑הּ וְהוֹצִ֜יאוּ אֶת־בְּתוּלֵ֧י הַנַּֽעֲרָ֛ה (כתיב הנער) אֶל־זִקְנֵ֥י הָעִ֖יר הַשָּֽׁעְרָה:
The girl’s father and her mother [shall obtain evidence…]: Let those who raised this evil offspring be disgraced because of her. — [Sifrei 22:90]
אֲבִי הנערה וְאִמָּהּ: מִי שֶׁגִּדְּלוּ גִּדּוּלִים הָרָעִים יִתְבַּזּוּ עָלֶיהָ (עי' שם):
16And the girl's father shall say to the elders, "I gave my daughter to this man as a wife, and he despised her;        טזוְאָמַ֛ר אֲבִ֥י הַנַּֽעֲרָ֖ה (כתיב הנער) אֶל־הַזְּקֵנִ֑ים אֶת־בִּתִּ֗י נָתַ֜תִּי לָאִ֥ישׁ הַזֶּ֛ה לְאִשָּׁ֖ה וַיִּשְׂנָאֶֽהָ:
And the girl’s father shall say [to the elders]: [The father, but not the mother.] This teaches us that a woman is not permitted to speak in the presence of her husband [when others are present]. — [Sifrei 22:91]
וְאָמַר אֲבִי הנערה: מְלַמֵּד שֶׁאֵין רְשׁוּת לָאִשָּׁה לְדַבֵּר בִּפְנֵי הָאִישׁ (שם):
17And behold, he made libelous charges, saying, 'I did not find evidence of your daughter's virginity.' But this is the evidence of my daughter's virginity!' And they shall spread the garment before the elders of the city.      יזוְהִנֵּה־ה֡וּא שָׂם֩ עֲלִילֹ֨ת דְּבָרִ֜ים לֵאמֹ֗ר לֹֽא־מָצָ֤אתִי לְבִתְּךָ֙ בְּתוּלִ֔ים וְאֵ֖לֶּה בְּתוּלֵ֣י בִתִּ֑י וּפָֽרְשׂוּ֙ הַשִּׂמְלָ֔ה לִפְנֵ֖י זִקְנֵ֥י הָעִֽיר:
and they shall spread the garment: This is a figurative expression, meaning: they shall clarify the matter as [“clear”] as a [new] garment. — [Sifrei 22:92, Keth. 46a]
וּפָֽרְשׂוּ הַשִּׂמְלָה: הֲרֵי זֶה מָשָׁל, מְחֻוָּרִין הַדְּבָרִים כַּשִּׂמְלָה (שם; כתובות שם):
18Then, the elders of that city shall take the man and chasten him.     יחוְלָֽקְח֛וּ זִקְנֵ֥י הָֽעִיר־הַהִ֖וא אֶת־הָאִ֑ישׁ וְיִסְּר֖וּ אֹתֽוֹ:
and chasten him: [with] lashes. — [Sifrei 22:93, Keth. 46a]
וְיִסְּרוּ אֹתֽוֹ: מַלְקוּת (שם):
19And they shall fine him one hundred [shekels of] silver because he defamed a virgin of Israel, and he should give it to the girl's father. And she shall be his wife; he shall not send her away all the days of his life.        יטוְעָֽנְשׁ֨וּ אֹת֜וֹ מֵ֣אָה כֶ֗סֶף וְנָֽתְנוּ֙ לַֽאֲבִ֣י הַנַּֽעֲרָ֔ה כִּ֤י הוֹצִיא֙ שֵׁ֣ם רָ֔ע עַ֖ל בְּתוּלַ֣ת יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל וְלוֹ־תִֽהְיֶ֣ה לְאִשָּׁ֔ה לֹֽא־יוּכַ֥ל לְשַׁלְּחָ֖הּ כָּל־יָמָֽיו:
20But if this matter was true: [indeed,] no evidence of the girl's virginity was found.     כוְאִם־אֱמֶ֣ת הָיָ֔ה הַדָּבָ֖ר הַזֶּ֑ה לֹֽא־נִמְצְא֥וּ בְתוּלִ֖ים לַנַּֽעֲרָֽה (כתיב לנער) :
But if this matter was true: [as corroborated] by witnesses, and there was warning, [proving] that she had committed adultery after her betrothal. — [Keth. 44b]
וְאִם־אֱמֶת הָיָה הַדָּבָר: בְּעֵדִים וְהַתְרָאָה, שֶׁזִּנְּתָה לְאַחַר אֵרוּסִין (כתובות מ"ד):
21they shall take the girl out to the entrance of her father's house, and the men of her city shall pelt her with stones, and she shall die, for she did a disgraceful thing in Israel, to commit adultery [in] her father's house. So shall you clear away the evil from among you.        כאוְהוֹצִ֨יאוּ אֶת־הַנַּֽעֲרָ֜ה (כתיב הנער) אֶל־פֶּ֣תַח בֵּֽית־אָבִ֗יהָ וּסְקָל֩וּהָ֩ אַנְשֵׁ֨י עִירָ֤הּ בָּֽאֲבָנִים֙ וָמֵ֔תָה כִּי־עָֽשְׂתָ֤ה נְבָלָה֙ בְּיִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל לִזְנ֖וֹת בֵּ֣ית אָבִ֑יהָ וּבִֽעַרְתָּ֥ הָרָ֖ע מִקִּרְבֶּֽךָ:

The answer is already in the question, in Rashi on verse 20

Aha. So this is after the fact, so after she was betrothed and she went and was intimate with another man.  What is considered betrothed these days? Engagement?

For hundreds of years now we've been doing the betrothal ceremony as part of the wedding itself; this avoids a number of halachic conundrums

Rashi to perek 22:

ואם אמת היה הדבר. בְּעֵדִים וְהַתְרָאָה, שֶׁזִּנְּתָה לְאַחַר
אֵרוּסִין (כתובות מ"ד): ואם אמת היה הדבר
BUT IF THE THING BE TRUE — proven by evidence of witnesses and after
legal warning that she had committed adultery after her betrothal
(Ketubot 44b).

